# Ansible check user is in inventory

Tags: ansible

I have a problem right now, I am trying to check if a user, that is in a variable in the inventory, exists in a destination host, but I can't define the `when` clause correctly.

I only want to know if theIuser exists or not, i don't wanna to create it if doesn't exists.

```yaml
- name: checking owner_user
   user: 
     name: "{{ owner_user }}"
     state: present
   check_mode: yes
   register: status

- name: Fail if owner_user not exists
  fail:
    msg: BAD user
  when: status.state == absent
```

How can I describe when to give me a fail message when the user doesn't exist?

Comment: Can you try `when: status.state is not defined`, you fail when the variable is not defined/exists.

Answer (score 2):

Supplying with an answer: Right now your `when` statement checks if the `status.state == absent`, how can we be sure that the attribute `state` is defined when a user does not exists? If you're unsure of what data your registered variable(s) contains, I would advise to use the `debug`-module and create a test case you can check what the `status`-variable contains, e.g

```yaml
- name: checking owner_user
   user: 
     name: "{{ owner_user }}"
     state: present
   check_mode: yes
   register: status

- name: output result above
  debug:
    msg: "{{ status }}"


OUTPUT If User Exists:
    "msg": {
        "append": false,
        "changed": false,
        "comment": "",
        "failed": false,
        "group": 1001,
        "home": "/home/test",
        "move_home": false,
        "name": "test",
        "shell": "/bin/bash",
        "state": "present",
        "uid": 1001
    }


OUTPUT If User does NOT Exists:
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false
    }
}
```

From the example above we can see that when a user does not exists, there's no attribute named `state`, and we can therefore replace current when statement with something like: `when: status.state is not defined`, or maybe better check if the uid of a user does not exists `when: status.uid is not defined`.